# Class dependency graph with doxygen

Tags: c++, dependencies, doxygen, code-analysis, static-analysis

I want to generate a class dependency graph for a large project in C++. I'm trying to do it with [doxygen](http://doxygen.org/). Here is the sample code:

```
class Used {
public:
  void bar();
};

class Base { };

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void foo(Used*);  // Dependency on class Used
};
```

Here is the collaboration diagram generated by doxygen:

[image]

Nice, but `Derived` depends on `Used` through the method `foo`, and I want to see this on the diagram, like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, doxygen generates such dependency only if `Used` is aggregated with `Derived` (used as a class member). Is there a way to show other kinds of dependencies between classes?

Or maybe someone can suggest a different tool to generate such a dependency graph?

I tried to use [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/), it does exactly what I want, but unfortunately it currently has some issues with dependencies in a really big project (though the dev team is open for communication and has already fixed a couple of bugs I reported).

Comment: Please, don't draw useless graphs for C++ code. Such techniques would never work with e.g. recursive template classes.

Comment: Are you using it with or without graphviz?

Comment: @cup Yes, HAVE_DOT is set to YES.

Comment: did you send any mail to support@cppdepend.com to help you understand the problem with your projects?Many times it's due to configuration rather than bugs.

Comment: @IssamfromJArchitectTeam Yes, I did, we have an email thread with 50 letters for now. Some bugs are fixed, some seems to be ignored, and some are claimed to be fixed in the next version, but there is no new version.