# How can doxygen generate a call graph that includes the class that is invoked in the implemention file (.cpp file)

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen is a great tool for C++ codes documentation. It is very impressive to see that the call graph is also generated in the documentation with doxygen. However, I found the generated call graph cannot find the invoked class that is called in the implementation file (.cpp) file. I give the following example to pinpoint my question:

header.h

```
/**
* Class A
*/
class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
}

/**
* Class B
*/
class B
{
    public:
        int c;
        int d;
}

/**
* Class User
*/
class User
{
    public:
        Class A a;
        void fun();
}
```

header.cpp

```
void User::fun()
{
    Class B b;      
}
```

In the above example, `class User` will use both `class A` and `class B`. The difference is that `class A` is used more explicitly as it is a member of class User. So in the call graph generated by doxygen, we can clearly see that `class A` is invoked by `class User`. But `class B` is not visible in the call map. Any ideas to make sure `Class B` is also in the call graph?

EDIT:
This question is related to [doxygen Dependency Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992759/class-dependency-graph-with-doxygen), another question raised in StackOverflow.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What are the settings you use (the ones different from the standard Doxyfile)? What happens when you document fun? (Oops a bit an old question).